# Java 8 lambda Expression for reading contents of the list and storing the counts of repeating values in list to a map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a `List<String>` which is like,

```
List<String> dummyList=Arrays.asList("a","b","c","a","b","d","e","f");
```

I need to traverse through the list and need the count of only "a","b","c" from list and store the alphabet as key and count of presence of same alphabet as value.

The final map which i have to get is like following keys and with the counts,

```
a:2
b:2
c:1
```

Comment: Why do you need this specifically as a lambda expression?

Comment: It was a requirement.I have written code without lambda expression, but i was instructed to use lambda expression

Comment: Thank you guys for answering my question...

Comment: I need only the count of "a","b","c" count in a map with keep as alphabet and value as its count. Need a solution using lambda expression.